# How to deploy Asp.net app with database tables and contents

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service

Ok so first of all, I apologize if this is a question that's been asked many times. Please kindly direct me to the proper answer in that case.
The issue I have, however, is finding answers that are relevant to current technologies.

So I'm new to asp.net core and trying to learn some new things here that I don't have any experience with from past work. I am trying to understand right now how to deploy my database migrations as well as the content in the localdb along with my asp.net razor pages app.

Right now I'm just trying to get my app published to azure. I have no problem publishing the app itself, creating the app service on azure, linking it to my GitHub repo. I tried following the instructions from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app), but it fails to build the bundle in dotnet bundle migrations command and I don't know why.

But maybe this isn't even the best way to do things.
I would like to publish my applications with the database tables and contents I create while building the apps so that I don't have to hard code seed data, especially for things like user profiles.

Obviously working with databases is something I'm not familiar with.

So to state the question simply, how do I deploy my app to azure WITH the database tables and all of their contents? And once I've done this, how can I do the same deploying the app to a hosting environment?

If someone would be able to direct me to the relevant resources that actually work with the current tech, I'd be very grateful. It would be even better if some kind soul were willing to walk me through the process.
Thanks

As stated above, I have tried to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app).
Im running into problems with the following code snippet from the .github/workflows/master_(appname).yml file:

```
-name: dotnet bundle migrations
run: dotnet ef migrations bundle -p (appname)/(appname).csproj -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp/migrate
```

Here's what happens:

```
Run dotnet ef migrations bundle -p (appname)/(appname).csproj -o /home/runner/.dotnet/myapp/migrate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Building bundle...
Build failed. Use --verbose to see errors.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

since this is running in the github builder, I don't know how to see the details of the errors, so that makes it hard to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to the issue, though not by solving the direct problem I wanted to solve.

I ran an SQL query on my azure database to construct all the necessary tables, and then manually added some user values. I needed to have a user in the database so I could add the other necessary data.

This isn't exactly what I wanted to do, because there was additional data I would have liked to add, but this works.

What I learned from this experience, which might be of some use to others, is that I should not work so much with the localdb, but probably connect it with an azure db during development.